# Mongo ISO date format is not working in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, python-datetime

I tried to insert the current time in mongodb using pymongo like below as one of the field in collection,

```
"currenttime" : datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

It is inserted successfully and I see the following result in mongodb

```
"currenttime" : ISODate("2019-11-21T01:22:18.544Z")
```

When I try to query this result using the `$gt and $lt` It is not able to fetch using the following query

```
query = {"currenttime":
                 {"$gte": (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)).isoformat(),
                  "$lt": datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
                  }}
```

Printed form of query :

```
{'currenttime': {'$gte': '2019-11-21T00:34:29.150681', '$lt': '2019-11-21T01:34:29.150681'}}
```

Could someone help with this please, Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

As you did when you inserted the document, you need to use `datetime` objects in your query, not strings:

```
query = {"currenttime":
         {"$gte": (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)),
          "$lt": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    }}
```